# how to make talk back read progress bar amount instead of percentage in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a programmatically made progress bar and I wanted talkback to read me the number of items and not the percentage. I wanted him to read the same on instagram. Stories 1 of 6, Stories 2 of 6... how do I solve this? my progress bar code is like this and in the xml I have only a linear layout

```
  private fun storyState.setupStoryProgressBar() {
    if (binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.childCount == 0) { createProgressBars() }
    setProgressBarAnimation(
        binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.getChildAt(currentPosition) as LinearProgressIndicator,
        currentStoryScreen.storyTimeout.toLong(),
        getColorByMode(currentStoryScreen.mode.value)
    )
}


private fun storyState.createProgressBars() {
    var progressBarWidth = context?.resources?.displayMetrics?.widthPixels?.div(stories.size) ?: STORY_PROGRESS_BAR
    progressBarWidth -= (STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING * 2)
    (0 until stories.size).forEach { _ ->
        val progressBar = LinearProgressIndicator(requireContext())
        progressBar.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(progressBarWidth, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 1f)
        progressBar.setIndicatorColor(getColorByMode(currentStoryScreen.mode.value))
        progressBar.trackCornerRadius = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING
        progressBar.trackThickness = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING
        progressBar.trackColor = Color.parseColor("#A79AA9")
        progressBar.alpha = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_ALPHA
        progressBar.setPadding(STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 0, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 0)
        binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.addView(progressBar)
    }
    binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.requestLayout()
}



private fun setProgressBarAnimation(progressBar: LinearProgressIndicator, seconds: Long, color: Int) {
    resetProgressBars(color)
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR)
    animator.duration = seconds * STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_ANIMATION_DURATION
    val screenPosition = viewModel.getCurrentPosition()
    animator.start()
    animator.setAutoCancel(true)
    animator.doOnEnd {
        if (viewModel.getCurrentPosition() == screenPosition && isTalkbackOff()) {
            goToNextStory()

        }
    }
}


private fun resetProgressBars(color: Int) {
    val totalStories = binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.childCount
    val currentPosition = viewModel.getCurrentPosition()
    (0 until totalStories).forEach {
        val progressBar = binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.getChildAt(it) as LinearProgressIndicator
        progressBar.setIndicatorColor(color)
        if (it >= currentPosition || currentPosition == totalStories) {
            resetProgressBarAnimation(progressBar, 0)
        } else {
            resetProgressBarAnimation(progressBar, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR)
        }
    }
}


private fun resetProgressBarAnimation(progressBar: LinearProgressIndicator, amount: Int) {
    progressBar.clearAnimation()
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", amount, amount)
    animator.duration = 0
    animator.start()
    progressBar.progress = amount
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `contentDescription` for `linearLayoutStoryProgressBar` each time when the progress moves to the next story. You haven't provided all code, but I suppose it will be in `goToNextStory()` method:

```
fun goToNextStory(currentStory: Int) {
    ...
    linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.contentDescription = "Story ${currentStory} of ${stories.size}"
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped a lot, but for me it worked when I used view?.announceForAccessibility("Story ${position +1} de ${viewModel.getLastPosition()}")
Now I'm having a hard time just getting him to read the text on the stories screen whenever he switches screens, do you know how I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just add this text to this content description?

Comment: everytime i switch stories the text changes and so i can't get the talkback to focus on the text and read the current text

Comment: I mean you can make it like this view?.announceForAccessibility("Story ${position +1} de ${viewModel.getLastPosition()}. ${viewModel.getCurrentStoriesText()}")

Comment: I managed to do the same using this same method. thank you so much mikahail

Comment: mikhail Can I abuse your goodwill a little more? since I already solved the problem of it showing me the position of the current story and the last one, now I want to see a way for the talkback to no longer read the percentage , I already put importForAccebility"no" but it still didn't work, it always reads the story position and then percentage and wanted to ignore that

Comment: Please create a new question and provide the full code you have at this moment to not complicate and mix this question and answer

Comment: I already created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183743/remove-progress-bar-percentage-talkback-readout