# remove progress bar percentage talkback readout

Tags: kotlin

I have a problem where talkback always reads the percentage of my progress bar, how do I remove this?

I have a linear layout and a progress bar programmatically but. I already tried to put importForAccessibility"no" in the linear layout but it didn't work

código

```
private fun setupAccessibility () {
        if(position == 0) view?.announceForAccessibility(tvEnterStorySmallText.text)
        view?.announceForAccessibility(tvEnterStoryTitle.text)
        view?.announceForAccessibility("Story ${position +1} de ${viewModel.getLastPosition()}")

    }

    private fun StoryState.setupStoryProgressBar() {
        if (binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.childCount == 0) { createProgressBars() }
        setProgressBarAnimation(
            binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.getChildAt(currentPosition) as LinearProgressIndicator,
            currentStoryScreen.storyTimeout.toLong(),
            getColorByMode(currentStoryScreen.mode.value)
        )
    }

    private fun StoryState.createProgressBars() {
        var progressBarWidth = context?.resources?.displayMetrics?.widthPixels?.div(stories.size) ?: STORY_PROGRESS_BAR
        progressBarWidth -= (STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING * 2)
        (0 until stories.size).forEach { _ ->
            val progressBar=LinearProgressIndicator(requireContext())
            progressBar.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(progressBarWidth, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 1f)
            progressBar.setIndicatorColor(getColorByMode(currentStoryScreen.mode.value))
            progressBar.trackCornerRadius = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING
            progressBar.trackThickness = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING
            progressBar.trackColor = Color.parseColor("#A79AA9")
            progressBar.alpha = STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_ALPHA
            progressBar.setPadding(STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 0, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_SPACING, 0)
            binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.addView(progressBar)
        }
        binding.linearLayoutStoryProgressBar.requestLayout()
    }

    private fun setProgressBarAnimation(progressBar: LinearProgressIndicator, seconds: Long, color: Int) {
        resetProgressBars(color)
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, STORY_PROGRESS_BAR)
        animator.duration = seconds * STORY_PROGRESS_BAR_ANIMATION_DURATION
        val screenPosition = viewModel.getCurrentPosition()
        animator.start()
        animator.setAutoCancel(true)
        animator.doOnEnd {
            if (viewModel.getCurrentPosition() == screenPosition && isTalkbackOff()) {
                goToNextStory()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isTalkbackOff(): Boolean {
        val accessibilityManager = binding.root.context
            .getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager
        return accessibilityManager.isEnabled.not() &&
            accessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled.not()
    }
```

Comment: Attach the code you're using please

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten